# SQLite: how to highlight fields outside of trigger spec?

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I have an SQLite table as such:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |

and the following trigger specs that fire on update or insert for each column:

- A = 0
- B = 1

In the application, I need to display the rows that break the specs, with culprit fields highlighted, as such:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | ***0*** |
| ***1*** | 1 |

I honestly don't know how to approach this. Would this require that I somehow return a 'bitmap' of the table along with the selected data? Is there a better way to 'tag' fields?

Thanks!

Comment: DBMSs don't handle presentation of data. Do that in your application.

Comment: @KenWhite ok, but then that means having to copy the trigger semantics in application code and correctly parse each field according to those. Matching the semantics doesn't seem trivial to me. Maybe I could manage with two queries, the 1st returning the rows and the 2nd a SELECT CASE ... returning 1s for errors and 0s for values in-spec?

Comment: I don't know what the best solution for you might be. I can just say that you can't *highlight* data using SQL. If you can find some other way to write the statement to show what is significant, that would be the easiest solution, but you can't *highlight* specific values using SQL - that has to be done in your front-end application. You might return a column that you don't display in the UI that indicates whether the value should be emphasized, for instance, and do your formatting (highlighting) based on the value of that column.

Answer (score 1):

In a query all you can have is 2 extra flag columns (one for each of the columns `A` and `B`) with `0` or `1`:

```
SELECT *, 
       A = 0 flag_A,
       B = 1 flag_B
FROM tablename;
```

In your application you can check the values of the flag columns and highlight a column if its flag is equal to `0`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=760309330e3a518695bf3c67308a693a).